# Viewing sample data

Tags: r

I'm looking to do a qtl analysis using R Studio. To learn how it works, I've been using some of the sample data available in the package. The following produces workable results:

```
data(fake.bc)
summary(fake.bc)
plot(fake.bc)
```

However, I don't know how to view the contents of the source files that produce the graphs of genetics maps and such. How do I view the source files associated with fake.bc?

Answer (score 1):

If you want help about a dataset in your package, you can get it like with any other function :

```
?fake.bc
```

In this help page you can read :

```
Format:

     An object of class ‘cross’.  See ‘read.cross’ for details.
```

Then, if you read the `read.cross` help page, you will learn how the `fake.bc` object has been generated.